# Merge Overlapping date intervals in sql table

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table which contains shift sign in and sign out times of employees. Each record has AutoGenID, employeeID, start datetime and end datetime. Based on these data i want to find the hours of work for each employee for a given period of time such as a month.

This is not web based but a Mobile and a PC app which can run in offline mode.

The problem is that there may or may not be multiple records for a single employee with overlapping date intervals. This is because an employee can individually sigh in on multiple devices per day and all these entries are added on this centralized database table. Hence there may or may not be overlapping date intervals for a single employee.

For example lets say that user A signed in from his mobile at '2015-07-03 10:51:19' and later signed in again from his PC at '2015-07-03 12:36:14'

At the end of the day he signed off from his PC at '2015-07-03 18:12:29' and signed off his mobile at '2015-07-03 18:19:53'

And Next day he only uses his PC to sign in. So on the database i have the following records.

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID |   EmpID   |         start       |         End         |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  |   EM001   | 2015-07-03 10:51:19 | 2015-07-03 18:19:53 |
| 2  |   EM001   | 2015-07-03 12:36:14 | 2015-07-03 18:12:29 |
| 3  |   EM001   | 2015-07-04 11:34:52 | 2015-07-04 17:21:43 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

But when querying the data i only need the Hours the employee worked. So I need the first start time and the last end time if the dates are overlapping so that i can calculate the hours. Again this issue is there only for days with overlapping times and there may not be overlapping times for a single employee on some days.

This hour calculation is not for employee salary purposes. Its just to capture the work hour of the user.

So does anyone have any idea on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Wrong approach. Change your session code instead where you're logging the times of the employee. for example if the user signs in from a PC first have that time as the start time, ignore the second time he logs in as he already logged in once. The last time when he switches off from either of the devices.

Comment: That approach is not applicable to this situation because the system is running offline most of the time and will only be synced with the centralized server every couple of weeks.

Comment: You will still be maintaining the logs internally somewhere in that case? The point is before synching it should be possible to do so. Going the other way round is not the right approach IMO

Comment: Yeah but at the time of sign on the devices are isolated and will not know about previous sign on from other devices.

Comment: Have the active sessions stored in the database. so before logging in you check the sessions of the user. If the user already has an active session then you don't log that entry.

Comment: Keep the logs detail. If it is a calendar day solution then in the table that matters do a min of sign-in max of sign-off. If they fall asleep and you calc pay this way, jokes on you

Comment: It would not work on a offline environment

Comment: A good question for op is what are you trying to accomplish and let's start there

Comment: Record all user 'login' / 'logout' entries from any devices that they use. These are an 'audit trail' and information about what the user tried to do. It is not certain that 'logoff' entries will be recorded or supplied by the user. The user will ensure that the login attempts  will be recorded by the system as this is normally the requirement to be paid..

Comment: Its a mobile and PC application. At a particular location there might be number of mobile devices and PCs. So a single user might need to log in to one device or number of devices withing a shift. However the connectivity to the server is not guaranteed always so they individually maintain sign in records. When there is a connection to the server they sync these data. At the end of the month a report should be generated with the number of hours a user worked on a shift which means the initial device login and last device sighout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207124/merge-overlapping-date-intervals-in-sql-table#comment50416455_31207124 Again check for active sessions. I don't see a problem with this approach. For logging out you could have a number of devices logged in count and when there are no devices left you log that session out and make a sign out entry.

Comment: Insane report output i say :)

Comment: I cannot check for the active session when it is running offline.

Comment: You're not getting the point. Whenever you're trying to insert a record in your employee log times, just before that, check if the user has an active session. If so, don't make another entry to the table. If not, have an inital login time inserted. I'm gonna leave it at this.

Comment: Yeah i get that, but what if the device which the user signed on second is synced with the server first.

Comment: look at a LAG query to check the previous row to see if it is still the same 'work session'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dipen Shah has a point, but sometimes you can't change the way sign-ins are logged. In this case perhaps you can try grouping the table by the date and querying the min(start) and max (end) of every user and date, like this:

```
select empid, min(start), max(end) from signin group by empid, date(start);
```

Comment: This could work, although a single shift might be from one day starting at 10pm to the next day 8am.

Comment: Thanks unfairhistogram. Your way seems to be working